# System UI not responding

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run my previously working program and all of a sudden I am experiencing issues. This is the message I recieve but I don't understand what I need to do with it. I'm really new to this, thanks for the help

```
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\gnwa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: In the first line of your error message it says that the process could have been blocked by an antivirus. Have you checked whether this is the error?

Comment: Also, it says you should try setting the environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value larger than 5. If you don't know how to do this, you can refer to [this link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html)

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that :)

Comment: Check if you can manually run the executable C:\Users\gnwa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe.